# Annotation for text selection goes away with device rotation for new pspdfKit 5.3.6

Tags: pspdfkit

I am using pspdfKit for my app. Previously i was using 4.4.X version. Now I have upgrade it to 5.3.X.

After selecting text for annotation if i rotate the device the selection goes away. Previously it was staying. As far as user don't removes that by tapping on screen or somewhere else on screen. Same is happening with video after tapping on video if i rotate device it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

PSPDFKit founder here. I just tried that with 5.3.8 and can't reproduce the selection vanishing issue. Can you open a ticket on https://pspdfkit.com/support/request with your license? We can help you much faster over there. Thanks!